# Badges is not aligned with text firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

i faced this issue the badges are not  aligned with the text. i am using firefox.

[image]

it is fixed from other place still remaining at

[image]

Comment: I don't really follow. Can you show a screenshot of what it *should* look like?

Comment: @philwinkle i added the screen-shot you can see that.

Comment: I see now, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New design bug on Firefox](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/842/new-design-bug-on-firefox)

Comment: @QaisarSatti I'm pretty sure it's the exact same bug.

Comment: This issue is the same one as reported here: ["New design bug on Firefox"](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/842/new-design-bug-on-firefox)

Comment: @Hynes i see the issue is fixed still one place they are not fixed. check the updated question..

Comment: @QaisarSatti I would consider the new issue you raised [tag:status-bydesign] as that is how most badges look within that area across all community sites. And while I agree it could be nudged up a few pixels, the CSS here would affect all community sites and would take a little more time to iron out.